# In Powershell, how do I list CredSSP DelegateComputers as distinct objects?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, winrm

As is well known, to avoid the [Powershell Second Hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/) when Powershell Remoting, one needs to set the CredSSP Client and Server settings.

e.g.

```
# On the client, a.k.a the First Hop Server
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role "Client" -DelegateComputer "secondhop.example.com"

# On the server, a.k.a the Second Hop Server
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role "Server"
```

And now I can PSRemote to the "client" server and from there access resources on the "server" server. All good and well.

However, the environment is largeish, and *I want to know the "Client DelegateComputers" in effect on a good number of machines*. How do I achieve this?

I know I can `(Get-WSManCredSSP)[0]` to get a list of Client DelegateComputers. But this is presented as an ugly, unwieldy string which I would *very much like to not parse*, given that this is Powershell and that I am in love with the object oriented approach.

I would like to think that I have been all over `wsman:/` both using `Get-Item` and `Get-​WS​Man​Instance`, as well as googled through what reasonably must be all of Google.

It seems unthinkable that this is so elusive, I must have missed something embarrassingly simple.

So ServerFault, **how do I Powershell natively or using a direct .NET call get a nicely presented array or similar  of CredSSP Client DelegateComputers** on a given host?

I can run any version of .NET Framework and Powershell available on Win2008r2 and Win2012r2.

Comment: Some alternatives to using CredSSP are listed [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/)

Comment: Very nice! If you turn it into an answer with the link and citation of the solution text I will upvote and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, Google actually had one more page and [this is where the answer was hiding](https://blog.victorvogelpoel.nl/2014/03/03/powershell-get-wsmancredsspconfiguration-getting-credssp-configuration-for-local-or-remote-computers/).

The Client DelegateComputer list is stored in the Windows registry at:

```
HKLM:\software\policies\microsoft\windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentials
```

Reading this key is not beautiful, but it's better than the alternative.

So Victor Vogelpoel, all worldly glory to him, came up with the following oneliner:

```
((Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\software\policies\microsoft\windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowFreshCredentials).psobject.Properties | where { $_.Name -match "\d+"  } | select -expand value | foreach { if ($_ -like "wsman/*") { $_.substring(6) } else { $_ } })
```